# Angular observable subscription issue

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to use the observables the way that I don't have to worry about unsubscribing them. The way I got it setup is exactly the way based on this article which is on manner one.
Observable declaration

```
campaigns: Observable<ICampaigns[]>;
```

the http method:

```
  getCampaigns() {
    return this.http.get<ICampaigns>(this.BASE_URL + '/campaigns/');
  }
```

calling the getCampaigns method and assigning the values to the campaigns observable:

```
this.campaigns = this.getCampaigns();
```

I get this error underneath he call statement
[image]

Comment: should be ```return this.http.get<ICampaigns[]>(this.BASE_URL + '/campaigns/');```

Comment: and would be good of you mention the error and error line both, not just the error line.

Comment: Thanks @fatemefazli. That worked

Comment: your welcome, i posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be:

```
getCampaigns() {
   return this.http.get<ICampaigns[]>(this.BASE_URL + '/campaigns/');
}
```